# Adding styling to a form in Rails 4 causing f.submit button to not work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-submit, form-for

I am building a form in Rails4.  When I added divs for styling this form, the f.submit button stopped working.  I have not changed the controller or the model.  Code below.  Thanks!

## _form in the Plans View

```
 <div class="sidebar-widget">
                  <div class="Pricing-box">
                      <div class="price-title spacing-box">
                        <h4>Create a New Plan</h4>
                      </div>

                    <hr>
                    <div class = "sidebar-form"
                    <%= form_for(plan) do |f| %>

                      <div class="name-field">
                        <%= f.label :name %>
                        <%= f.text_field :name %>
                      </div>

                      <div class="time-field">
                        <%= f.label :time %>
                        <%= f.time_field :time %>
                      </div>

                      <div class="date-field">
                        <%= f.label :date %>
                        <%= f.date_select :date %>
                      </div>

                      <div class="restaurant-field">
                        <%= f.label :restaurant %>
                        <%= f.collection_select :restaurant_id, Restaurant.all, :id, :name %>

                      </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="spacing-grid">

                        <%= f.submit "Create Plan", class: 'btn btn-md btn-black'%>
                        <% end %>

                      </div>
                  </div>
```

## From the Plans Controller: new, index and create actions

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @plan = Plan.new
  end

  def create
    @plan = Plan.create(plan_params)
    @plan.users << current_user
    redirect_to @plan
  end

  def index

    @plans = Plan.all
    #binding.pry
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

## From the Plans view, index.html.erb

```
<section class="ptb ptb-sm-50">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 mt-xs-30">
                      <%= render "plans/form", {plan: Plan.new } %>
                      <%= render "plans/all_plans", {plans: @plans} %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What shows up in your log when you click the Submit button?

Comment: That is the correct syntax for a submit button in a form in Rails 4. Can you post the complete form code? Maybe some model/controller code as well.

Comment: @marsAtomic Strangely, nothing at all happens in the console.

Comment: if you remove the class does the submit button work?

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? The styling may merely be coincidental with your difficulties. The fact that your log shows nothing indicates that the button press is being ignored, and that smells like Turbolinks to me.

Comment: ooo turbo links is a good guess. It's the first thing to go whenever i start a new app

Comment: More context is needed - what's your form code and the submission code you're using?

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I changed the question to reflect the fact that the button isn't working even when I remove the class.  However: it worked without any issues before I began styling.  BTW I have disabled Turbolinks.

Comment: if you remove the class does the submit button work?

Comment: @andrewHendrie  It doesn't work even when I remove the class, which made me realize that's not the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your form_for tag so that it looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @plan, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

This is the syntax that the Rails guide recommends - not sure if this will solve your problem or not.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that (except that since this is a partial that will be used by different controllers I didn't use the instance variable--I define plan in the index.html.erb page that renders the partial) but it didn't work.  I think create is the default action for a form anyhow.